# How to be faster in neo4j when query path?

Tags: python, time, neo4j

There are about 1000nodes , 3600 relationships
and many ring in relationships.
There is query sql：

```
match p=(:Devices{name:"123.123.123.208"})-[r:Cost*1..7]->(:Devices{name:"123.123.123.20"}) 
with p,reduce(x=0,a in relationships(p)|x+a.Cost) as value 
order by value desc 
limit 1 
return p;
```

profile：[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid traversing loops, you may want to leverage [APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/), specifically the [path expansion procs](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_expand_paths):

```
MATCH (start:Devices{name:"123.123.123.208"}), (end:Devices{name:"123.123.123.20"})
CALL apoc.path.expandConfig(start, {terminatorNodes:[end], relationshipFilter:'Cost>', minLevel:1, maxLevel:7, uniqueness:'NODE_PATH'}) YIELD path
WITH path, reduce(x=0,a in relationships(path)|x+a.Cost) as value 
ORDER BY value DESC 
LIMIT 1 
RETURN path;
```

The NODE_PATH uniqueness ensures a node cannot be used more than once per path.